# Facebook Graph API occasional error: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I'm developping Facebook SDK Application using PHP SDK.
But I got SSL request error and still continue from 2hours ago.(nearly May 1st 0:00 UTC+0)

When I send request to Facebook GraphAPI with curl,

```
$ curl https://graph.facebook.com

curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
```

This error occurs on linux(I checked it by Amazon Linux and CentOS6.4), but sometimes getting normal JSON response. (try 10req, 9 is error, 1 is valid JSON)

and not occurs on OSX(marvericks)

with cacert from FB PHP SDK on github, this still occurs on linux except on OSX.

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/4.0-dev/src/Facebook/HttpClients/certs/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem
$ curl https://graph.facebook.com --cacert DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.pem

curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
```

so I quickly fixed to disable SSL Checking on PHP SDK.
are there any missing setting on my linux server?

Comment: I confirmed that this was a Facebook's SSL error. Now, above curl command results regular JSON.
Thank you @Flaxfield (I cannot do "Up Vote" as still new user)

Answer (score 2):

This was probably related to an SSL issue with graph.facebook.com earlier today. This should now have been resolved: https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/1653352648231195/